# changing css properties from an input value

Tags: jquery, css

I am in a class right now and my group and I are trying to create a game that allows kids to manipulate CSS using input values. For some reason though, I keep getting an error everytime I try to manipulate the DOM.

The Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'html' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement. (challenges.coffee.self-f525f98….js?body=1:18)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879)

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".code_generator").click(function() {
    answer = $("#answer").val()
    console.log(answer)
    $(".profile-picture").css("text-align", answer)
  })
```

The HTML:

```
    <p class="picture_positioning">img { <br> text align:</p>
        <input type="text" name="profile_pic" id="answer" />
        <button class = "code_generator" type="button">Submit code!
        </button>
```

Comment: *"I am in a class right now"* - And your teacher can't help? The code that you've shown works without error: https://jsfiddle.net/q1zww03s/

Comment: The class simulates real world development experiences.  We're not supposed to ask questions every time we need help.  We rely on the same resources that developers do.

Comment: I see why I got that error and now it's fixed, but when I type center or right into the input field and try to manipulate the DOM from input.val(), it doesn't work.  The elements remain unchanged.

Comment: But...again, the code shown works, including to set `center` or `right` via the input field. If you have fixed the original error and now have other problems, either [edit] the question to clearly explain the problem (include the relevant code), or consider asking another question specific to the new problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
<input type="text" name="profile_pic" id="answer" />
<button type="button" onclick="submit();">Submit code!</button>
```

the js submit function

```
function submit(){
  var my_input = document.getElementById("answer").value();

  var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("profile-picture")[0];
  obj.style.setProperty(my_input);
}
```

Comment: Why would you introduce an inline event handler attribute when the OP is currently binding a handler from JS? Also, the OP's code works as is: https://jsfiddle.net/q1zww03s/